# AngularJS mis-type between model and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, types, integer

I am receiving a list of objects from my server with the following format:

```
[ { 'id' : 1, ... }, { 'id' : 2, ... }, { 'id' : 3, ... } ]
```

I am trying to allow the user to select objects with a `radio` button. Here is the following HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="id" value={{ obj.id }} />
```

I am repeating this piece of code for every object in the list. Problem is, when clicking one of the buttons, the following error shows up:

```
Error: ngModel:numfmt
Model is not of type `number`
```

The ID of each object is clearly a number, as the following console log states:

`console.log(typeof (obj.id)); <- return 'number'`

But it still does not work. Can anyone help me discovering *why* does it break ?

**EDIT** The code iterating through the array of objects:

```
<ul ng-repeat="obj in objectList>
   <li>
      <label><input type="radio" string-to-number ng-model="id" value={{ obj.id }} />
      {{ obj.id }}</label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is not. `numfmt` refers to the error `numerical format` from Angular error auto-generated page. It states that the error is a `ngModel` error, and more precisely a `numerical format` error. Which makes no sense to me, because I double checked inside that controller that the data is effectively a number. :(

Comment: can you show the code that iterates through the array of objects?

Comment: Try `ng-model="obj.id"`

Comment: what does string-to-number do?

Comment: Sorry I took it off, it was a dirrecty which was supposed to transform a string to a number, but didn't work out

Comment: did you try @Guedes idea, that would be my next thought

Comment: Yes I did, I am not in condition to continue experimenting anyway, I'll take back on Monday :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML should be:

```
<ul ng-repeat="obj in objectList">
   <li>
      <input type="radio" name=group1 ng-model="group1.id" ng-value='obj.id' />
      {{ obj.id }
   </li>
</ul>
    <p>Model = {{group1.id}}</p>
</div>
```

There are several problems with the code

- The `ng-model` attribute needs to set to a property of an object. (Use a dot.)
- Use `ng-value` for Angular Expressions
- The radio button group needs to be defined with the `name` attribute.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofnuhb06/).